# I need to get the value of the id of the active tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="pills-COD">
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#a">Class A</a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#b">Class B</a></li>
     <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#c">Class C</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#d">Class D</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="a" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="tab-pane fade">
   <h3>Menu 1</h3>
   <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="c" class="tab-pane fade">
   <h3>Menu 2</h3>
   <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the `id` of the active tab whenever the pill is clicked using `jQuery`. 
For example, I need to get the value `"a"` whenever `li`, `"Class A"` is clicked.

I have found other researches made here in stack overflow, but .tabs() is not working for me in jQuery. Other solutions also show the href value, but I need tag id of the active tab.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that you are expected to have ***researched your issue and made attempts to write the code yourself before posting***, and include a summary of what you have tried so far. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to stack overflow that's why I didn't know that I have to post the attempts I made. I already tried other solutions found here but the don't work because .tabs() is not working for me in jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click of the anchor, you need get the `href` attribute without the `#` like this:

```
$(this).attr("href").replace("#", "")
```

[attr("href")](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets the `href` value from the clicked anchor. And [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), replaces the `#` with empty string.

Here's a snippet:

```js
$("ul.nav-pills > li > a").click(function() {
  console.log( 
    $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "") 
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="pills-COD">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#a">Class A</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#b">Class B</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#c">Class C</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#d">Class D</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="a" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3><p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3> <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="c" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3> <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find it looking at the list, you can do this:

```
var $activeLi = $('#pills-COD li.active');
var activeId = $activeLi.children('a').attr('href').substr(1);
```

Or, looking at the tabs:

```
var $activeTab = $('.tab-content .tab-pane.active');
var activeId = $activeTab.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and couldn't access the value of the clicked **nav-item**, Then I tried the below code, and it worked.

Html for nav-tabs:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#info-time-sheets">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block">@L("Info")</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="tab-non-processed" >
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#non-processed">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block">@L("Non processed ")</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" id="tab-previous-time-sheets">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#previous-time-sheets">
                            <span class="d-none d-sm-block">@L("Previous Timesheets")</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I got using `e.currentTarget.id` for id

```
$('.nav-tabs li').on('click', (e) => {
       
        if ((e.currentTarget.id === "tab-non-processed") || (e.currentTarget.id === "tab-previous-time-sheets")) {
            $("#generate-documents").show();
            $("#preview-timesheet").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#generate-documents").hide();
            $("#preview-timesheet").hide();
        }
    });
```